# Setting up Strapi using MongoDB via the PM2 Runtime

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04, pm2, strapi

I'm quite new to Strapi and I'm following the Strapi deployment documentation at https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/deployment.html#configuration. I have setup strapi using mongodb and it seems to work both in production and dev on my server. I can create content types and add data...

Now I'm trying to start Strapi using the PM2 Runtime. I have setup the `ecosystem.config.js` file (see below) and I run `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`. The Strapi app seems to start just fine, but now what happens in the browser is that I am prompted with a new admin user. Seems like all users and data is lost... Mongo db not accessed or whats going on?

this is my ecosystem.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'cms.strapi',
    cwd: '/var/www/domain/public_html',
    script: 'server.js',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
      DATABASE_HOST: '127.0.0.1',
      DATABASE_PORT: '28015',
      DATABASE_NAME: 'db-name',
      DATABASE_USERNAME: 'db-u-name',
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'pw',
    },
  }],
};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hello, can you please share your database.json files, production and development please

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jim and thanks for your reply! I believe the problem was a mixup between the prod and the dev environment. Sorry, my bad. I thought I was in one environment when I was really in the other. I guess it should be obvious when you start the server from the prompt whether your starting **dev** or **prod**, but once the web server is up and running in the browser I guess you can't tell from the gui whether it's the one or the other. At least I can't find one other than that the admin usernames (and possibly data) are different... Hmm..

Anyway my production/database.json file looks like this:
`{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "mongoose",
      "settings": {
            "uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017/db-prod",
        "database": "db-prod",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "srv": false,
        "port": 27017,
        "username": "u-name-prd",
        "password": "pw"
      },
      "options": {
            "ssl": false
      }
    }
  }
}`

PM2 Runtime seems to be working correctly with Strapi and Mongo now :-)